# Magento 2 : How to Create Custom Pricing Calculator on Category Page?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to know that how to create an Extension for Custom Pricing Calculator on Category Page.The functionality of Pricing Calculator is use Based on the bellow Image. when I fill the all details and click on Place Order button. It will show cart page.

[image]